# What to do in Chicago during an 8-hour stopover?

Tags: transit, trains, public-transport, chicago, ord

We are travelling from Ireland to Kansas with an 8 hour stopover at Chicago O'Hare (arriving Thursday at 12 noon) and leaving at 8 pm.

Can we leave the airport and what would you recommend we could do with those couple of hours?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Your question as noted is too open-ended to be answerable here; however, see *[Can I visit Chicago during a 5.5 hour layover in O'Hare?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4780)* It takes about an hour on the Blue Line to reach downtown, after which you should have plenty of time to an architecture tour boat, browse a museum, shop at Marshall Fields, or even watch a Cubs game.

Comment: @pnuts: They have to get past border control anyway, since their onward flight is domestic.  After that, they are free to roam the US at will, and nothing prevents them from leaving the airport.

Comment: There is US preclearance at both Dublin and Shannon airports, so it doesn't matter which; you'll come into Chicago the same as a domestic passenger. You'll not have to worry about your checked baggage, and you'll have plenty of time to get out and roam around the city.